# How can I select all active products with variants in Rails query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two models: `Product` and `Variants`. `Prouduct has_many :variants` and `Variant belongs_to :product`. I need a query, that will select all active products with variants. I tried this:

`@products = Product.joins(:variants).where('products.active =?, true)`, but it doesn't seem to be the solution. Doing in the view something like this:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <% if proudct.variants.any? %>
    <!-- Do something here... -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

is not an option. Can you help me to build a correct query? Thanks ahead.

Comment: What are _active_ products?

Comment: Just a boolean field in the db

Comment: You need to join the tables then filter according to active column (Active = True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`joins`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins).

Straight option:

```
Product.joins(:variants).where(products: { active: true })
```

More conventional:

define a scope on `Product` model:

```
scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
```

Use it:

```
Product.active.joins(:variants)
```

If you want to be even more laconic, you can change your scope to something like:

```
scope :active_with_variants, -> { joins(:variants).where(products: { active: true }) }
```

Usage is, as you might have guessed, simple:

```
Product.active_with_variants
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason, I have duplicated records, so I just put `uniq` method at the end of the query.

Comment: @AlexZakruzhetskyi use `distinct`, it's more SQLish